# MNIST ValueError when checking target in Keras

Tags: neural-network, keras, theano, mnist

My code is as follows:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(output_dim=500, input_shape=(28, 28)))
model.add(Activation("tanh"))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, nb_epoch=50, batch_size=20)
```

This gets the following Error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_2 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (60000, 10)
```

I think the shape (60000, 10) is the shape of `y_train` and this has 2 dimensions while expected 3 dimensions somewhere.

Where should I edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MNIST samples are images of 28 x 28 values (pixels). You want to classify with an ANN that only takes in a 1-dimensional array of numbers (imagine the first layer of your ANN as a 500 long row of neurons that only understand a 500 long row of numbers but not a 28x28 matrix).

To fix your error you have to reshape your data beforehand:

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

X_train = X_train.reshape(60000, 784)
X_test = X_test.reshape(10000, 784)
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, 10)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, 10)

...

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(784,)))
```

If you want to feed in your data in 2d to achieve more accuracy by preserving the spatial order of your images rather than flatten them out to a long list of numbers than you have to change your models architecture to a Convolutional Neural Network (lots of example code online, especially for MNIST).